# Laravel append attributes with related relation will cause reach maximum function nesting level

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
class Order extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['test'];

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');
    }

    public function getTestAttribute()
    {
        return $this->orderItems->first()->id;
    }
}

class OrderItem extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['test'];

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }

    public function getTestAttribute()
    {
        return $this->order->id;
    }
}
```

Given models with above definitions, when I called `Order::find(1)->toArray()` I will get the following errors.

```
Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
```

How should I avoid this issues ? It seems there is recursive call

```
select * from orders where order.id in (?)
```

```
select * from order_items where order_items.order_id in (?)
```

Thanks!

Comment: in `OrderItem` return `$this->order_id` instead of `$this->order->id`

Comment: Un... @Aless55 your answer is work, but only for this example code. Actually what I want to get is something not in order_item table, like $this->order->total_charge.

Answer (score 0):

You can just don't append order in OrderItem. Right Now what you are calling is:

 Order -> first OrderItem -> Order -> first OrderItem -> 
and repeating.

If you in other place want OrderItem with Order. just do `OrderItem::with('order')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel resource collection, hope it will fix looping issue